# how to retrive specific portion of string from console of mule to the flow

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component

I am new to mule.I am validating a excel file which is inputing using a UI.If the file is wrong i am getting a "error message" and "show what the error is" in the mule console. My problem is that

How to take the value from the console of mule and show that value in the UI

Answer (score 0):

First you will need to take a look at Exception Strategies(http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Error+Handling). Here is the documentation that shows how to extract the exception cause and message and return to a client: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Exception+Strategy+Most+Common+Use+Cases#ExceptionStrategyMostCommonUseCases-ReturninganErrorMessage